# How can I customize the display of product categories in a Woocommerce shop on Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

[Product and category display right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNUYp.png)

Right now products on the main Woocommerce store page on my site display what categories they belong to, as seen in the attached image, the categories are "Author" , "Collection".

As you can see, the categories are separated by commas.
I want to change the commas for hyphens "–" .

So, using the pictures example, the categories would be displayed as such:
Daniel Cristancho – Colección Ópera Prima

I went into the meta.php file at
my-active-theme/woocommerce/single-product/meta.php
and used the following code to change the category separation from commas to hyphens, but it only affected the category display of the individual product page (as seen in photo), not the main store page.
[Categories displayed correctly only on single-product view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8uT3.jpg)

This is the code I used at the meta.php file:

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

global $product;
?>
<div class="product_meta">

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_start' ); ?>

    <?php if ( wc_product_sku_enabled() && ( $product->get_sku() || $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) ) : ?>

        <span class="sku_wrapper"><?php esc_html_e( 'SKU:', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="sku"><?php echo ( $sku = $product->get_sku() ) ? $sku : esc_html__( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></span>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php echo wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id(), ' - ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', count( $product->get_category_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>

    <?php echo wc_get_product_tag_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', count( $product->get_tag_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end' ); ?>

</div>
```